# Array_Constrain error even after I remove it

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a sheet with several ARRAYFORMULA(IF....) formulas. I think it was adding 1000s of extra empty rows to my sheet, so I wrapped them in ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF...)),300,1
For some instances I get the error: "Wrong number of arguments to ARRAY_CONSTRAIN. Expected 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments."

In an effort to troubleshoot, I removed the ARRAY_CONSTRAIN completely, but I still get the same error! I copied the formula to a notepad, deleted the cell contents, and pasted it back in without AC, and STILL the same error. Any ideas why?

Here's a formula where AC works:

=Array_Constrain(ArrayFormula(IF($B$4:$B$250="",,
IMPORTRANGE($F$4,"Summary!N4:N250")+IMPORTRANGE($F$5,"Summary!J4:J250"))),300,1)

And one where it doesn't:

=Array_Constrain(ArrayFormula(IF($AA$4:$AA$250="",,
IMPORTRANGE($F$4,"Summary!AA4:AA250")+IMPORTRANGE($F$5,"Summary!W4:W250"))),300,1)

I've double-triple-quadruple checked my parenthesis and all seems fine.

Comment: Both formula looks fine. Did you check data on those ranges?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: ```so I wrapped them in ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF...)),300,1 For some instances I get the error: "Wrong number of arguments to ARRAY_CONSTRAIN. Expected 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments."```, the ```,300,1``` should be put inside ```ARRAY_CONSTRAIN()```, which means it should be ```ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF...),300,1)```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The first IF statement was checking to see whether a reference cell was blank - IF($AA$4:$AA$250="",, - and that reference cell's AC formula did have a parenthesis out of place. So the legit error in AA4:AA250 was being passed on.

Sorry for the false alarm - I was super tired when I posted and should have taken another stab with a fresh brain first.